# bc is ignoring scale option

Tags: linux, bash, bc

I can't figure out why bc tool sometimes ignores the scale option.

Here is an example:

```
> echo 'scale=2; 2.777 - 1.4744' | bc
1.3026
```

Expected result is:

```
1.30
```

Additional information:

```
> bash --version
GNU bash, version 2.05b.0(1)-release (x86_64-suse-linux)
Copyright (C) 2002 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
> bc --version
bc 1.06
Copyright 1991-1994, 1997, 1998, 2000 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

as Carl pointed out, if you check man page, you can find that line. it is about expression explanations. subtraction won't read `scale` variable. If you want to get the expected result (1.30), you could:

```
kent$  echo 'scale=2; (2.777 - 1.4744)/1' | bc 
1.30
```

`/` operation will read `scale` variable.

Comment: This tool needs to be killed with fire. The insanity.

Comment: @AquariusPower Probably the [REPL implementation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) of a language you know & trust, still not as convenient as bc though, especially when it comes to large numbers.

Comment: @AquariusPower: Qalculate! is probably the best alternative you can imagine. Anything bigger would be a mathematical suite. It can solve for unknowns, factorize, simplify, do matrix math with complex numbers, use CSV files, deal with units and prefixes easily, has loads of predefined variables, units, functions and many settings, even loads current exchange rates off the Internet if requested, and allows using real Unicode math symbols like e.g. ⋅ for multiplication. Its GUI allows plotting and defining new functions/variables/units too. (Hint, in scripts, use `-t` for terse mode.)

Comment: now i will add  division to 1 to make scale work as expected bc <<< "(expr)/1". amazing architecture

Answer (score 5):

From the [`bc(1)` man page](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/bc/):

> Unless  specifically  mentioned  the scale of the result is the maximum
>    scale of the expressions involved.

`1.4744` has scale `4`, so that's what happens to your expression.

Comment: And: Division uses the `scale` variable, but not addition, subtraction, or multiplication. They use the scale of the operands. "`expr / expr`: The  result of the expression is the quotient of the two expressions.  The scale of the result is the  value  of  the  variable `scale`."

Comment: @Carl, thanks for your answer, but it did not make sense when taken out of context from the manual. So I'm choosing Kent's answer as he even provided a workaround.